# /root is running out of space

Tags: boot, partitioning, root, home-directory, disk-usage

So, I'm running into a bit of a problem and being a noob at this
isn't really helping.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad with a 16Gb SSD and a 500Gb HDD.

My idea was initially to install the OS on the SSD and the rest
on the HDD. That way it should boot and run faster (right?).

I installed the /root on the SSD and the /home on the HDD.
So far it's been working great until I recently started getting
notifications saying I'm running out of /root space.

I combed through different forms and such and have ran all the
*sudo apt-get autoremove*
*sudo apt-get autoclean*
and managed to free up about 1Gb of space. Not really enough
though.

I've ran *sudo du -h --max-depth=1* in root and this was the
result:

```
3.6G    ./lib
14M     ./etc
12K     ./media
13M     ./sbin
4.0K    ./cdrom
5.7G    ./usr
du: cannot access ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
1.2M    ./run
32K     ./tmp
653M    ./boot
4.0K    ./srv
72K     ./root
9.8M    ./bin
4.0K    ./mnt
du: cannot access ‘./proc/599/task/599/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/599/task/599/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/599/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/599/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
0       ./proc
4.0K    ./lib64
5.3G    ./home
11M     ./kws
4.0K    ./dev
960M    ./var
16K     ./lost+found
954M    ./opt
0       ./sys
17G     .
```

Why is there a 5.3Gb /home if I placed my home on the HDD? (probably
a stupid question).

**Is there anyway I can reduce the used space in /root?**
or
**Is there a way I could have the OS on a different drive than the rest?**

Thanks,
Nooby McNoobface

Comment: (1) You ran `du`, which displays storage used. Thus `5.3 GB /home` is the amount of space used; it says nothing about the amount of space available. (2) Try running `df -H` (you don't even need `sudo`) which may be more informative. (3) Try not to confuse `/` and `/root`.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to look at

- The size of /var looks like there might be logs taking up space
- The size of /boot and /lib suggests there are a number of unneeded kernels installed

If you add the -x flag to the du command it will not cross mount points, ie if you do du -x / it will not report the space in /home (assuming it's separate mount)

Personally I use this command to find what's taking up space:

```
sudo du -ax / | sort -nr | less -S
```

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the logs and some of the older kernels. That cleared up some amount of space.